# Удаляем гласные буквы из строки

Tags: java

Есть ли возможность учитывать оба регистра, а не записывать буквы всех регистров в vow?

```
public class NotVowels{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(disemvowel("This website is for losers LOL!"));

    }
    public static String disemvowel(String str) {
        String[] vow = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"};
        for(int i = 0; i < vow.length; i++){
            str = str.replace(vow[i],"");
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте str = str.replace(vow[i].toUpperCase(),""); в цикл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
public static String disemvowel(String str) {
    String[] vow = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
    for(int i = 0; i < vow.length; i++){
        str = str.replace(vow[i],"");
        str = str.replace(vow[i].toUpperCase(),"");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: тоже была такая мысль, спасибо

Answer (score 5):

```
public static String disemvowel(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]","");
}
```